# Why bother avoiding `Cursor.getCount()` when `moveToNext()` calls it anyway?

Tags: android, performance, android-cursor

Conventional wisdom says to avoid calls to [Cursor.getCount()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getCount()) because it's an expensive operation.
After digging through [AbstractCursor source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/database/AbstractCursor.java), it seems all standard operations including `moveToNext`, `moveToFirst`, and `moveToPosition` all call `getCount` internally!

So what's the point of avoiding calling it yourself at all?

EDIT: added hyperlink to Android docs

EDIT: Perhaps I stand corrected?
I was under the impression that a Cursor can provide a moving window over large data sets, whose full length can only be known once the window has perused the entire set at least once. Hence calling `getCount` would cause a full load/iteration, and moveToNext advances the window only as necessary.

Comment: What makes you think that avoiding `getCount()` is "conventional wisdom"?

Comment: You need extra boilerplate code if you use `getCount` and also you should reference conventional idea via post etc. There may be another point.

Comment: What "conventional wisdom"? Avoid calling it when? The [SQLiteCursor's](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursor.java) `getCount()` certainly isn't heavy. It just returns a variable. Same for MatrixCursor. MergeCursor might be a little intensive since it contains a list of child Cursors, but it doesn't seem terrible.